# ANGULAR - Subscribe in component don't update value from service

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a observable in my service that I want to subscribe.

In the first time, the good initial value is returned, thanks to BehaviorSubject.

But when I update the value using next() in my service, the subscribe in my component is not called ...

This is the code in my service :

```
    activeDeepView:any = false;
    deepViewStatus: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    deepView(){
      this.activeDeepView = !this.activeDeepView;
      this.deepViewStatus.next(this.activeDeepView);
      console.log("deep view status", this.deepViewStatus);
    }
```

And this is the code in my component :

```
this.globalFn.deepViewStatus.subscribe(value => {
  console.log(value);
  if(value == true){
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.fsModal.nativeElement,'transition','0.3s ease-out');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.fsModal.nativeElement,'pointer-events','all');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.fsModal.nativeElement,'transform','translateY(0px)');
  } else {
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.fsModal.nativeElement,'transition','0.3s ease-out');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.fsModal.nativeElement,'pointer-events','none');
    this.renderer.setStyle(this.fsModal.nativeElement,'transform','translateY(1000px)');
  }
})
```

Where is my error ? I'll be glad to learn, because I've try many things and nothing works at this point ...

Thank you all !

Comment: And is `deepView()` called from the same component your subscription is in, or from elsewhere?

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your answer, it's called from another component and providerIn:root is in my service, it have to be in component ?

Comment: It sounds like you have a standard setup. Can you recreate your problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: Does it get completed by chance? This looks fine, show us other parts of the code

Answer (score 1):

You can try to expose BehaviorSubject as an Observable.
In your service:

```
private deepViewStatus: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
...
status(): Observable<boolean> {
  return  this.deepViewStatus.asObservable();
}
```

And then you would subscribe in your component this way:

```
this.yourService.status().subscribe(value => {//your code})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not work, nothing happens ... :/

Answer (score 0):

I give you a simple architechture that respects POO, reactive & clean code principles

**checkbox.service.ts** & **checkbox.component.ts**

```ts
@Injectable()
export class CheckBoxService {
  private _stream$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor() {}

  public getStream$(): Observable<boolean> {
     return this._stream$();
  }

  public toggle() {
    const currentValue = this._stream$.getValue();
    this._stream$.next(!currentValue);
  }
}

@Component()
export class CheckBoxComponent implements OnInit {
  private isSelected$ = new Observable<boolean>();

  constructor(
    private checkBoxService: CheckBoxService
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.isSelected$ = this.checkBoxService.getStream$();
  }

  public checkboxToggled() {
    this.checkBoxService.toggle();
  }
}
```

**checkbox.component.html**

```html
<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="isSelected$ | async" (ngOnChanges)="checkboxToggled()">
```